# CKEditor 4.5 filetools, how to set XHR.withCredentials = true,

Tags: ckeditor

In CKEditor 4.5 beta, filetools plugin fails to set cookies while using cross domain upload url, for CORS to enable cookies we require to set **XHR.withCredentials = true** while upload XHR getting initiated.

How can i set XHR properties in filetools plugin in CKEditor 4.5.

Answer (score 5):

You can get access to XHR object by listening to [fileUploadRequest event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-fileUploadRequest) and then you can set `withCredentials` flag to `true`.

```js
editor.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( evt ) {
    var xhr = evt.data.fileLoader.xhr;

    xhr.withCredentials = true;
} );
```

Working development sample is available [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/uploadwidget/dev/cors.html).

Comment: If using ckeditor4-vue, then use add the component's @ready event handler and add adelura's method to the method you call. <ckeditor @ready="onEditorReady"></ckeditor> https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_vue.html#ready

Answer (score 0):

To the Extension of Adelura's answer.

```
 editor.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( event ) {
      var fileLoader = event.data.fileLoader;
      fileLoader.xhr.withCredentials = true;
 }, null, null, 100);
```

add weightage to your event so that it trigger before XHR send and after XHR open. In filetools plugin it has couple of similar events which has weightage of 5 and 999 respectively.

```
editor.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( evt ) {
                var fileLoader = evt.data.fileLoader;

                fileLoader.xhr.open( 'POST', fileLoader.uploadUrl, true );
            }, null, null, 5 );

            editor.on( 'fileUploadRequest', function( evt ) {
                var fileLoader = evt.data.fileLoader,
                    formData = new FormData();

                formData.append( 'upload', fileLoader.file, fileLoader.fileName );
                fileLoader.xhr.send( formData );
            }, null, null, 999 );
```

so you make sure your event triggers between weightage 5 and 999